"settlement day" setting in QuantLib for bootstrapping the interest rate curve
I have been attempting to bootstrap zero rates/discounting factors using QuantLib. It seems to me that the results I obtained using QuantLib are pretty close to Bloomberg values for SONIA curve, and the tiny difference is coming from the setting of "settlement day". I can see there are three different places for setting the settlement days. My questions are that

Why we have so many places (i.e., 3) for setting the settlement days? What is the difference between these three settlement days?
How should I set them properly to match the dates on Bloomberg as well as the zero rates/discounting factors?

The SONIA curve:

The code for bootstrapping the SONIA curve:
import pandas as pd
import QuantLib as ql

ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = ql.Date(31,3,2024)

tenors = ['1W', '2W', '1M', '2M', '3M', '4M', '5M', '6M',
          '7M', '8M', '9M', '10M', '11M', '12M', '18M', '2Y',
          '3Y', '4Y', '5Y', '6Y', '7Y', '8Y', '9Y', '10Y',
          '12Y', '15Y', '20Y', '25Y', '30Y', '40Y', '50Y']
tenors = [ql.Period(elem) for elem in tenors]

rates = [0.051897, 0.051923, 0.051995, 0.051946, 0.0518332, 0.051594, 0.051227, 0.0508879,
         0.050582, 0.050225, 0.049843, 0.049495, 0.049105, 0.0487496, 0.045902, 0.044009,
         0.041145, 0.039342, 0.03813, 0.03734, 0.03687, 0.036655, 0.036582, 0.0366596,
         0.036865, 0.03718, 0.037355, 0.03722, 0.03688, 0.03602, 0.03502]

yts = ql.RelinkableYieldTermStructureHandle()
index = ql.Sonia(yts)

helpers = [ ql.OISRateHelper(2, tenor, ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(rate)), index)
            for tenor, rate in zip(tenors, rates)]     # (1) 1st parameter of OISRateHelper

# (2) 1st parameter of PiecewiseLinearZero
curve = ql.PiecewiseLinearZero(0, ql.TARGET(), helpers, ql.Actual365Fixed())

yts.linkTo(curve)
engine = ql.DiscountingSwapEngine(yts)

end_dates = []
zeros     = []
dfs       = []

for tenor, rate in zip(tenors, rates):
  ois_swap = ql.MakeOIS(tenor, index, rate)     # (3) MakeOIS also has the "settlementDays"
  end_date = ois_swap.maturityDate()
  discount_factor = curve.discount(end_date)
  zero_rate = curve.zeroRate(end_date,  ql.Actual365Fixed(), ql.Continuous).rate()
  
  end_dates.append(ois_swap.maturityDate().ISO())
  zeros.append(zero_rate*100)
  dfs.append(discount_factor)

df = pd.DataFrame({"End Date": end_dates,
                   "Market Rate": [rate * 100 for rate in rates],
                   "Zero Rate": zeros,
                   "Discount": dfs} )

print(df)

The corresponding outputs:
      End Date  Market Rate  Zero Rate  Discount
0   2024-04-11      5.18970   5.187119  0.998722
1   2024-04-18      5.19230   5.187134  0.997729
2   2024-05-07      5.19950   5.187306  0.995038
3   2024-06-04      5.19460   5.172656  0.991112
4   2024-07-04      5.18332   5.150910  0.986962
5   2024-08-05      5.15940   5.116214  0.982631
6   2024-09-04      5.12270   5.070005  0.978700
7   2024-10-04      5.08879   5.026710  0.974844
8   2024-11-04      5.05820   4.986522  0.970922
9   2024-12-04      5.02250   4.942034  0.967241
10  2025-01-06      4.98430   4.894457  0.963279
11  2025-02-04      4.94950   4.851759  0.959886
12  2025-03-04      4.91050   4.805656  0.956726
13  2025-04-04      4.87496   4.762188  0.953245
14  2025-10-06      4.59020   4.503075  0.934166
15  2026-04-07      4.40090   4.298952  0.917073
16  2027-04-05      4.11450   4.016498  0.886189
17  2028-04-04      3.93420   3.837486  0.857431
18  2029-04-04      3.81300   3.716625  0.830160
19  2030-04-04      3.73400   3.637912  0.803664
20  2031-04-04      3.68700   3.591703  0.777467
21  2032-04-05      3.66550   3.571906  0.751081
22  2033-04-04      3.65820   3.566932  0.725122
23  2034-04-04      3.66596   3.578299  0.698918
24  2036-04-04      3.68650   3.605767  0.648440
25  2039-04-04      3.71800   3.646886  0.578375
26  2044-04-04      3.73550   3.670615  0.479588
27  2049-04-05      3.72200   3.650446  0.401113
28  2054-04-06      3.68800   3.596970  0.339536
29  2064-04-08      3.60200   3.451368  0.251061
30  2074-04-04      3.50200   3.263510  0.195341

